# "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index" in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to display the "NDA ID" in a label When the user click on the select link in the grid view. But it gives the error as "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index".

Here is my code,

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdNDA" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" Font-Size="Small" Width="95%" onselectedindexchanged="grdNDA_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NDA ID" DataField="NDAid" DataFormatString="ISM/C/NDA/IT/{0}" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Company Name" DataField="ComName" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Country Incorperated" DataField="Country" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Created" DataField="Date" />
     </Columns>

     <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
     <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
     <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView> 

<br>
<asp:Label ID="lblValues" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Code behind

```
protected void grdNDA_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
   lblValues.Text = "<b>ID:</b> " + grdNDA.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
}
```

Comment: When you debug this, how many items are in `grdNDA.SelectedRow.Cells`?  The code assumes there are at least 4 items, are there?

Comment: SelectedRow.Cells[3] is the point of  Exception.. You will need to check index actually exist before assigning value .

Comment: You said you want to display `NDA ID` which is at first position, I think your code should be `grdNDA.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text` but still you need to debug and see what you are getting in `grdNDA.SelectedRow.Cells` as the error message is self explanatory.

Comment: @David yes there are four items

Comment: @Madushi: Then you're going to need to debug this to find out where the exception is coming from and what the runtime value is that's triggering it.  Somewhere you're trying to access an item outside the bounds of an array.  If the code you're showing us isn't the problem, find the code that is.

Comment: @David I get a null value when I added a break point to `lblValues.Text = "<b>ID:</b> " + grdNDA.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;`

Comment: @Madushi: There are *several* things on that line of code which could be `null`.  Can you be more specific?  Also, a `NullReferenceException` isn't the problem you've described so far.  Where is the actual exception that's being thrown?  And what is the runtime value of the array being indexed at that time?  You need to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this line

```
lblValues.Text = "<b>ID:</b> " + grdNDA.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

It worked using this

```
protected void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    System.Data.DataRow dr;
    dt.Columns.Add("NDAid");
    dt.Columns.Add("ComName");
    dt.Columns.Add("Country");
    dt.Columns.Add("Date");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = i;
        dr[1] = "Company " + i;
        dr[2] = "Country " + i;
        dr[3] = DateTime.Now;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    grdNDA.DataSource = dt;
    grdNDA.DataBind();
}

protected void grdNDA_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblValues.Text = "<b>ID:</b> " + grdNDA.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

ASPX

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onload="form1_Load">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="grdNDA" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" Font-Size="Small" 
        Width="95%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdNDA_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NDA ID" DataField="NDAid" DataFormatString="ISM/C/NDA/IT/{0}" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Company Name" DataField="ComName" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Country Incorperated" DataField="Country" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Created" DataField="Date" />
         </Columns>
         <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView> 
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblValues" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```